# How to use async/await in python 3.5+

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I was trying to explain an example of async programming in python but I failed.
Here is my code.

```
import asyncio
import time

async def asyncfoo(t):
    time.sleep(t)
    print("asyncFoo")


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncfoo(10)) # I think Here is the problem
print("Foo")
loop.close()
```

My expectation is that I would see:

```
Foo
asyncFoo
```

With a wait of 10s before `asyncFoo` was displayed.

But instead I got nothing for 10s, and then they both displayed.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I explain it?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZzfHjytDceU might be helpful

Comment: I don't think it is fair to put this question on hold. He clearly says he wants to "Foo" to be printed before "asyncFoo".

Comment: FWIW, `time.sleep` is *also* blocking. Async is useful for resuming execution while waiting for **IO**, not blocking the thread.

Comment: You might wanna use asyncio.sleep(10) instead. Also please note loop.run_until_complete is a blocking one, so you might wanna have two async functions, one for the "slow foo" and one for the "fast foo". I wanted to post a complete answer but unfortunately somebody has put this question on hold.

Comment: Now it's open. You can explain now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`run_until_complete` will block until `asyncfoo` is done.  Instead, you would need two coroutines executed in the loop.  Use `asyncio.gather` to easily start more than one coroutine with `run_until_complete`.

Here is a an example:

```
import asyncio


async def async_foo():
    print("asyncFoo1")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print("asyncFoo2")


async def async_bar():
    print("asyncBar1")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("asyncBar2")


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(async_foo(), async_bar()))
loop.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your expectation would work in contexts where you run your coroutine as a `Task` independent of the flow of the code. Another situation where it would work is if you are running multiple `coroutines` side-by-side, in which case the event-loop will juggle the code execution from `await` to `await` statement.

Within the context of your example, you can achieve your anticipated behaviour by wrapping your coroutine in a Task object, which will continue-on in the background without holding up the remainder of the code in the code-block from whence it is called.

For example.

```
import asyncio

async def asyncfoo(t):
    await asyncio.sleep(t)
    print("asyncFoo")

async def my_app(t):
    my_task = asyncio.ensure_future(asyncfoo(t))
    print("Foo")
    await asyncio.wait([my_task])

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(my_app(10))
loop.close()
```

Note that you should use `asyncio.sleep()` instead of the `time` module.

Comment: it prints foo but fails to print asyncfoo.

Comment: The event loop is exiting before the task completes. One way to keep the event loop open is to use `loop.run_forever()`, another way is to assign the task to a variable, e.g. `my_task_var` and then wait for the task to finish using `await asyncio.wait(my_task_var)`. In this case, await the task variable at a location that doesn't block your code execution, e.g. Place it after the print("Foo") statement.

Comment: @Scripting.FileSystemObject updated answer with version that now works and exits automatically. (Have been away from a computer for a few weeks...)

Answer (score -1):

`run_until_complete` is blocking. So, even if it'll happen in 10 seconds, it will wait for it. After it's completed, the other print occurs.

You should launch your `loop.run_until_complete(asyncfoo(10))` in a thread or a subprocess if you want the "Foo" to be print before.

Comment: I see little gain with more complexity of using async with python. Why can't it be as simple as in node?

Comment: Running async *and* a thread/subprocess misses the point in this example.